# How to launch iOS app via custom URL and allow to open a webpage if it's not installed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, url

I'd like to be able to send invitation in an email to a specific "event" happening inside my iOS app. So I figured I'd need to use custom URL. That's fine.

But I'd also like to be able to handle the user that doesn't have the app installed yet, to be taken to a mobile Safari and to the webpage with installation instructions for the app.

What would be the best way to do it? 
I could try the following:

1. In the email I send a link to a http://www.example.com/joinevent/?id=foo
2. User is taken to a Safari webpage that sends a redirect to `mycustomscheme://joinevent/?id=foo`
3. If the user doesn't have the app installed this redirection won't work and he stays in the Safari - I could then handle the displaying of installation instructions probably.

But this approach doesn't seem "natural" for me. Is there a better/more native way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://rdrct.it

It is a web service that allows you to achieve exactly this functionality very easily.

**Full disclosure - I created rdrct.it**

Here's the basics:

1. Login to the site, create a project for your particular app. Choose a unique code (this could be the name of your app).
2. You'll then be provided with a URL in the form: http://rdrct.it/uniqueCode
3. Once you've done that, you need to register the app's ID in the app store, and also details about the custom URL scheme. Tick "Auto-redirect" - what it will then do is try to open the app, and if that fails, it will automatically send the user to the app store.
4. If the app is opened, then the querystring is also passed to the app, so in your example case, the device will have been served: **mycustomscheme://joinevent/?id=foo**

It also works across multiple device types, so if you have the app available for Blackberry, Android or Windows Phone, then it will also do the same for those depending on which device type the user is using.

Like I said, I created it, but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Distimo to track you app analytics, they provide a shortlink to your apps that can be used also used to track conversions. It shows a custom page depending on the device used to access. This is especially convenient if you have the same app published in the AppStore, Google Play, Amazon, etc.